# Pass table to postgreSQL function, execute select statement, return table

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql, procedural-programming

I'm transitioning to postgreSQL from MSSQL and still working out the syntax for procedural programming. The idea is to create a function that will take a table as an input/parameter, execute a series of `SELECT` statements against this input table (no temp tables; the `SELECT` statements will be executed with CTEs), and `RETURN` a final table.

The input table would be very straightforward:

```
Col_1      Col_2       Col_3
----------------------------
2           5           12
```

I want to use each of the fields in the input table to calculate a number (in this example, summing `Col_1`, `Col_2`, and `Col_3`), append it to the input table, and create an output table that appears as such:

```
Col 1      Col_2       Col_3      Col_4
---------------------------------------
2           5           12        19
```

My attempt at the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION summing_function(input_table)
RETURNS output_table(Col_1 INT, Col_2 INT, Col_3 INT, Col_4 INT) AS
$$
SELECT 
    i.*
    , i."Col_1" + i."Col_2" + i."Col_3" as sum
INTO output_table
FROM input_table i
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Obviously everything between the dollar quotes is incomplete/wrong. What's the correct postgreSQL syntax for piece between the dollar quotes?

Comment: Isn't a view what you want to use instead ? (this question is not a way to say you should use a view, but a real question from me to understand why a view can't be the right tool to use here)

Comment: A view could very well be the better solution. I was just trying to get some clarification on general postgreSQL syntax and constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not pass a "table" as a function argument. You *can* pass the name of a table to a PL/pgSQL function and then run a [dynamic query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION summing_function(input_table text)
    RETURNS TABLE (col_1 int, col_2 int, col_3 int, col_4 int) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
        format('SELECT *, col_1 + col_2 + col_3 FROM %I', input_table);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```